# How to implement localstorage for current open tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, session-cookies, browser-cache

I am followed this [link](https://jsbin.com/pipekiqofo/edit?html,output) for store the data on my browser for radio buttons. Issue is If I opened same url in another tab, the radio buttons are selected as per previous tab.

Functionality is - Submit button redirect into another page. So, What I need is local storage of that particular current opened tab and particular link only.

code I am using

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes" />
<title>Save state of checkbox on refresh using JavaScript</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" class="save-cb-state" name="mycheckbox" value="asdf"> Must I save my state?</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" class="save-cb-state" name="anothercheckbox" value="1"> Try and save this</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" class="save-cb-state" name="mycheckbox2" value="qwer"> This can be saved as well.</li>
    </ul>  
<script>
// Avoid scoping issues by encapsulating code inside anonymous function
(function() {
 // variable to store our current state
  var cbstate;

  // bind to the onload event
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    // Get the current state from localstorage
    // State is stored as a JSON string
    cbstate = JSON.parse(localStorage['CBState'] || '{}');

    // Loop through state array and restore checked 
    // state for matching elements
    for(var i in cbstate) {
      var el = document.querySelector('input[name="' + i + '"]');
      if (el) el.checked = true;
    }

    // Get all checkboxes that you want to monitor state for
    var cb = document.getElementsByClassName('save-cb-state');

    // Loop through results and ...
    for(var i = 0; i < cb.length; i++) {

      //bind click event handler
      cb[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        // If checkboxe is checked then save to state
        if (this.checked) {
          cbstate[this.name] = true;
        }

    // Else remove from state
        else if (cbstate[this.name]) {
          delete cbstate[this.name];
        }

    // Persist state
        localStorage.CBState = JSON.stringify(cbstate);
      });
    }
  });
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the question, *maintain the same values between tabs* or *each tab has own storage space*? As abit unclear what you mean by If I opened same url in another tab, the radio buttons are selected as per previous tab. What I need is local storage of that particular current opened tab and particular link only.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone At  First - Product page was opened and some radio buttons are selected and try to launch the product by using submit button, but after page loaded they show some alert message like "Some tick boxes are not selected". Now I closed the tab and open the same link in another new tab. This time I opened a new freash page (but same link - Woocommerce product page) with same link - here some tick boxes are ticked  because of localstorage.

Comment: use sessionStorage instead of localStorage. sessionStorage is valid only for that session. Once you close a tab, the values stored in the browser session will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to manage it by using sessionStorage rather than localStorage. More info on the difference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Answer (score 1):

Just change the content localstorage into sessionStorage. Below are the updated code and solution for this Question (How to implement localstorage for cureent open tab?).
Answer is:

```
<script>
// Avoid scoping issues by encapsulating code inside anonymous function
(function() {
 // variable to store our current state
  var cbstate;

  // bind to the onload event
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    // Get the current state from localstorage
    // State is stored as a JSON string
    cbstate = JSON.parse(sessionStorage['CBState'] || '{}');

    // Loop through state array and restore checked 
    // state for matching elements
    for(var i in cbstate) {
      var el = document.querySelector('input[name="' + i + '"]');
      if (el) el.checked = true;
    }

    // Get all checkboxes that you want to monitor state for
    var cb = document.getElementsByClassName('save-cb-state');

    // Loop through results and ...
    for(var i = 0; i < cb.length; i++) {

      //bind click event handler
      cb[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        // If checkboxe is checked then save to state
        if (this.checked) {
          cbstate[this.name] = true;
        }

    // Else remove from state
        else if (cbstate[this.name]) {
          delete cbstate[this.name];
        }

    // Persist state
        sessionStorage.CBState = JSON.stringify(cbstate);
      });
    }
  });
})();
</script>
```

and Special thanks to @Jacob Nelson